# EventToCommand not running

Tags: c#, ninject, visual-studio-2013, mvvm-light

I am running `mvvmlight` commands in a few applications and all is well so I don't have a coding issue.
when I run it on my dev computer the command runs fine and opens a child window as desired.
as soon as I release it to new PC's hitting the button no longer works. it just runs dead. no error or anything back.
I am also running ninject 3.0
I did change the target framework half way through due to incompatibilities with dev express grid. I think this is the reason.
any ideas to refresh the system maybe.
I have already reinstalled via nuget packages and no go again.
am now thinking of total rebuild which would be annoying.
thanks in advance 
Scott 
edit. downgraded from .net framework 4.5 to 4 (target framework)

Answer (score 0):

As anticipated. Full rebuild to a brand new solution has solved the problem. Must be some confusion on references. Scott